# meaning of ftp -s in shell scripting

Tags: shell, shell-script

can some me tell me what does `s` means in `ftp -s` (shell scripting)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming, that you're on a Windows machine and not on *nix (as "shell" suggests). On Windows "ftp -s:filename.dat" stands for the default ftp client which reads it's commands from the file "filename.dat". So the -s switch tells the client to read a list of commands from a file and execute them.

Current ftp client on *nix does not have that switch, so if you're on a *nix machine please show part of your script, so we can investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

From the `ftp` manual page:

> -s srcaddr     Uses srcaddr as the local IP address for all connections.

If you simply mean what `-s` means in general: it means that it is a "switch" or "option". These "options/switches" let you change the behavior of a command without having to go too deep into it and without having to edit any default settings.

So, if you were to translate `ftp -s SRCADDR` into English, it would say:

> Do the `ftp` command but use SRCADDR instead of the default local IP address for this session.